# Sonar-scanner gives an error called "Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property"

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm getting an error called "Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property" when executing the sonar-scanner command.
I have referred most of the currently available solutions within Stack overflow, git hub etc. However, none of these solutions have worked out successfully.

Additional Details:

Java Version : 13.0.2
SonarQube Version : sonarqube-8.2.0.32929
Sonar Scanner Version : sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-windows

The sonar-scanner conf file properties are mentioned bellow.

```
sonar.projectKey=SampleProject1
sonar.projectName=SampleProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=C://itpm123//SampleProject//src
```

Thank you very much and any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to do what the error message suggest: add a property `sonar.java.binaries=C://itpm123//SampleProject//classes` (the path is just a wild guess, supply the path to your actual compiled classes)

Comment: okay, thank you for your reply and put your time on this ill try the solution that you provide me .thank you again.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it worked successfully! @Thomas Kläger, kindly provide your comment as an answer, so that I can accept that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do what the error message suggest: add a property

```
sonar.java.binaries=C://itpm123//SampleProject//classes
```

to your sonar-scanner conf file properties (the path is just a wild guess, supply the path to your actual compiled classes)